Terminology for data literal/identifier expression
In the following SQL statement:
SELECT
    1,
    myField,
    myField+1
FROM
    myTbl

The third column is often referred to as an "operator expression". Is there a name for the type of expression in the first column (a literal) or second column (a variable/identifier)?

You always ask challenging questions. All of them are just "expressions". Depending on the parser/engine/database/grammar they can take different names, In this case they could be: literal, column, numeric expression.

I'd say myField is a bit misleading column name. E.g. select (a,b) c from ... returns one column (a row-type), having two fields. 'The terms column, field, and attribute refer to structural components of tables, row types, and structured
types, respectively, in analogous fashion. As the structure of a table consists of one or more columns, so does the structure of a row type consist of one or more fields and that of a structured type one or more attributes.' (ISO/IEC 9075-2:2023(E), 4.15 Columns, fields, and attributes.)

BTW, column names (and other names) are identifiers.

Arguably:
SELECT
    1,           -- added constant column or constant value
    myField,     -- table column          or column
    myField+1    -- added derived column  or derived value 
FROM
    myTbl        -- table name or table

